# not able to commit some files on gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I am quite new on GitLab hence I have very naive question

[image]

this image is screenshot of my GitLab repository 
as you can see on screen shot internal_external@ba01dda6 is not folder

but in my local repository it is folder with name Internal_external and it has several files which need to be part of my remote master branch on gitlab but whenever I try to commit files from Internal_external folder using command

```
git add .
git commit -m "bla bla message"
git push origin master
```

files from internal_external are not get updated on gitlab
as well as git diff shows no difference between local and and remote repository on GitLab

Comment: Forget gitlab for a second, did that `git add .` add the files, and did `git commit` create a commit with those files? Start there.

Comment: What kind of output does `git status` respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found solution 
In image second file like symbol shows git submodules
so just removed submodule fron Internal_external and now I can commit those changes 
to remove submodule I followed this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule)

Answer (score 0):

1. Commit the changes in your local git repository
2. Switch to the respective directory of GitLab
3. Push all the files into it